# Why does an order preserving function have to have this form?

Tags: set-theory

For $\alpha$, $\beta$ ordinals with an order preserving bijection $f$, why is $f(\xi)=\{ f(\mu):\mu < \xi\}$ for $\xi \in \alpha$?

It's a part of a proof I'm trying to understand, but I cannot see why this should be the case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Hint*: an order-preserving bijection between totally ordered sets has order-preserving inverse.

Comment: Roughly speaking, as you march along increasing elements of the domain, if you skip an element in the range you can't go back later to get it, as that wouldn't be order preserving. So at each "step" you have to pick the next unused one, and for ordinals, that's the set of all previously used ones. That's how I'd think of it, though I don't know that that's a good basis for a rigorous proof.

Comment: @JonathanZ Really nice intuitive explanation! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the case. Let $\alpha=3$. Define $f$ by $f(0)=6, f(1)=7, f(2)=8$. Then $f$ is a bijection and order preserving. And $2 \in 3$ and $\{f(\mu):\mu \lt 2\}=\{f(0),f(1)\}=\{6,7\}$. And $\{6,7\}\ne 8$.

EDIT: Updated under the assumption that $\alpha,\beta$ are ordinals and $f$ is a bijection from $\alpha$ to $\beta$

Assume $\alpha,\beta$ are ordinals and $f$ is a bijection from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ and $f$ is order preserving using $\in$ as the order on both $\alpha,\beta$.

We claim  $f(\xi)=\{f(\mu)|\mu\in\xi\}$.

Suppose $\eta\in \{f(\mu)|\mu\in\xi \}$. Then $\eta=f(\mu)$ for some $\mu\in\xi$. As $f$ is order preserving, $f(\mu)\in f(\xi)$ and so $\eta\in f(\xi)$.

Suppose  $\eta\in f(\xi)$. Then as $\beta$ is the codomain of $f$, $f(\xi) \in \beta$ and so $\eta\in\beta$ and so as $f$ is onto $\beta$,  $f(\delta)=\eta$ for some $\delta\in\alpha$. And so $f(\delta)\in f(\xi)$. Suppose  $\xi\underline{\in}\delta$. Then as $f$ is order preserving, $f(\xi)\underline{\in}f(\delta)$, a contradiction. Hence $\delta\in\xi$ and $\eta\in \{f(\mu)|\mu\in\xi \}$.

Hence $f(\xi)= \{f(\mu)|\mu\in\xi\}$.

Comment: Note that the codomain has to be an ordinal, too. So either your $f$ is not a bijection (e.g. it misses $3$), or it has inappropriate codomain ($\{6,7,8\}$ is not an ordinal).

Comment: Thanks Noah, good pickup. But where does it state that the codomain of $f$ is an ordinal? (and if it's not the case, I think more info is required in the question to be able to answer it).

Comment: "$\alpha,\beta$ ordinals with an order preserving bijection." So we're looking at a bijection between two ordinals.

Comment: OK, updated under this assumption. To me it was a little unclear about the bijection part. I have also assumed that the order under consideration is $\in$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to phrase this claim is that $f(\xi)=lim_{\mu<\xi}f(\mu)$ for $\xi\in\alpha$, which is equivalent to requiring that $f$ is a continuous map from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. If $f$ were not continuous, and there were some "gap" in $\beta$ between $\{f(\mu)|\mu<\xi\}$ and $f(\xi)$, we can ask which $\gamma\in\alpha$ gets sent into that gap, since the function is a bijection. From our setup, we would have that $\gamma>\xi$ (or else it would be one of the $\mu<\xi$ and map below the gap) but that $f(\gamma)<f(\xi)$.

Comment: The rephrasing using lim is valid only for limit ordinals.